# Disposing components in an Eclipse view issue

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have few components in a view and I am disposing them by clicking on a hyperlink as below -

```
        toolkit.dispose();
        form.dispose();
        imageHyperlink.dispose();
```

Before disposing I appended a line to add components named Browser as -

```
browser = new Browser(parent,0)
browser.setUrl("www.....com");
```

The components are getting disposed properly, but to find the browser, I need to restore the view,means I need to double click on the view tab, then only the browser URL is coming up.
How to resolve this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a work around to solve the above. Since the after dispose, the view was expecting restore to refresh again, so I appended the size of the view every time after each refresh like this -

```
parent.setSize(getViewSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getShell().getSize());
```